# Codeigniter Dynamically load controller depending on url (outside routes.php)

Tags: codeigniter, controller

using CodeIgniter normally one has to specify the controllers in the config/routes.php file.
This is not to handy, so I would like to be able to do something like this in a controller.

1. get url parts and check if the first part is specified in an array
2. if so, load the specified controller, if not, load default controller.

It basically mimics the behavior of the routes file, but there is no need to specify the wildcards before. I am using a base controller I extend with every controller, but I would like to have this controller just load (or include) the needed controller.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this in a good way?

Thanks in advance.

// Edit

Okay, so here is my scenario.

I have cms and users can choose to include modules (e.g. a gallery).
I need to inlcude all the gallery php scripts without having to have "gallery" in the url.
I figured it would work if I use a "main controller" which loads another controller depending on the modules chosen. I realize this might not be the best way, so if there is a "clean" way to do it, please tell me.

As far as I know models are just for database stuff, so putting a whole gallery in there is not right either. The Plugin itself will of course be a library, but there is going to be some code to load the libs depending on the demands, get the database data, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing this is incorrect. You never should take over the routing function to do this. What you need is to use some kind of module functionality to include the required methods and models; a module doesn't require to have route-accessible methods, so it's basically a "library" with a model and views.

If I remember correctly there are several plugins that provide this, One was `HMVC` (google it).

The ideal form would be to load the "Module" on demand from your controller, like you do with the core CodeIgniter Libraries; so lets say you're inside the blog controller action and you want to include the `comment` module which is used on `gallery` and on `images`, you just include the module and call it's methods to get the data which you can then pass to the view as needed; you can even render partials and store them into a variable to pass to your master controller.

Hope this is enough to get you on the right track :)

Comment: Well, it is nearly enough. My problem now is, what do I use? 
Which files in codeIgniters structure is the right one to hold the code to load the libs and initialize those. 
Lats say I want to call the comment lib, I need to call it, pass the database configs and call the functions for showing a field to enter a comment as well as the latest comments. 
Where do I call the three methods? 
Because if I would do it in the controller I would have to include all possible “modules” in the controller beforehand. 
I would rather be able to include all files for a module without editing other files.

Comment: Lets say you're inside Post controller using the view method (action), you'll load the comment module from there, so then you can access the comments library by using `$this->comments`; the comments class (module) should have all the required methods and configurations for it to work; if you wish to have a config file you should add it inside the config directory and then load it via the API provided by CodeIgniter. From there, lets say you want to load the view that displays all the comments; you can do it in several ways. (continues on next message)

Comment: The first way is to call a method inside the module that will return a comment array which you'll include in your view. The other is calling a method which calls a partial and instead of rendering it to the browser it's stored in an array which you then can use from your controller / original view. For a modular approach the second one is the best since you'll have module views inside the module directory.

Comment: Naaa, its not really what I want, but I guess there is no way to have it the way I want, so I have to think of a different way to do it. Thanks for it anyway, it is a good solution nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question but you want to load your controllers if you go to them and if not you want to go to your default.

If I am understanding correctly you can do a couple things in your routes have a route that takes everything to your default controller.

In your controller have an array of all your controllers then implode the array to a regular expression

```
$array = [c1, c2, c3, c4];
$str = implode('|', $array);
$regex = "($str)"
```

now just add your regex to a route

now redirect as you see fit.

But this is really what the routes file is for you you are just dancing around something that should be used.

Comment: Well, I think this is not what I meant. I will try to specify my question, I do realize I have probably posed it to vague.